# Why does butanoic acid have a higher boiling point than isobutyric acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, boiling-point

Why does butanoic acid have a higher boiling point then isobutyric acid, when they have similar molar mass and molecular structure?

Butanoic acid ($\ce{C4H8O2}$) has a molar mass of 88.11 g/mol, the boiling point is 163 °C, and intermolecular force of H-bond.

[image]

Isobutyric acid ($\ce{C4H8O2}$) has a molar mass of 88.11 g/mol, the boiling point is 155 °C, and intermolecular force of H-bond.

[image]

Comment: Same reason why n-Butane has a higher boiling point than Isobutane: More intermolecular van der Waals interaction.

Answer (score 2):

In general, linear chains are more easily structured and packed than branched ones.  You need more energy to disturb the more relatively packed structure.This could explain why butanoic acid has a higher boiling point than isobutyric acid, and yet they are isomers.

Comment: Structuring and packing is usually an argument when talking about the melting point, right? How relevant would it be for liquid $\to$ gas?

Comment: There is higher energy needed to get away from liquid.